# Bash script to pass variable across functions

Tags: bash

I have removed parentheses, but still I was not able to fetch `ENV_NODE` value in second function `scpTAR`. Please let me know what is wrong.

```
set -x  
MASTER_HOSTNAME=`hostname | cut -d . -f1`  
TARGET_ENVIRONMENT = it  
evaluateEnvProp(){  
  if [ ${TARGET_ENVIRONMENT} = it ]; then  
    ENV_NAME=it && ENV_NODE=1cf62108e084   
  fi  
}  

scpTAR() {  
  echo ENV_NODE  
  echo ${ENV_NODE}  
  if [ ENV_NODE = ${MASTER_HOSTNAME} ] ; then  
    echo "scpTAR ENV_NODE = ${MASTER_HOSTNAME} " 
  else   
    "echo 'scpTAR ssh other node than jenkins server ENV_NODE=${MASTER_HOSTNAME}'"    
  fi       
}   

main(){    
  scpTAR    
}    

main
```

Comment: Variables are by default global variables.

Comment: I am using ${ENV_NAME} in scpTAR function but its corresponding value which we set as "it" in evalEnvProp function is not getting values as "it" where am i getting wrong

Answer (score 3):

As [@cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073900/bash-script-to-pass-variable-across-functions#comment83121761_48073900) said, variables are global by default. What you did is setting the variables in a [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html):

`( ENV_NAME=it && ENV_NODE=xyx && ENV_WLS_DOMAIN=user1 && ENV_NODE_PATH=path )`

Because of that, these are gone (not propagated to calling script's environment) once the subshell exists. This is why you do not see their values set in `scpTAR` function. Remove the parentheses and your code should start working.

**Update**

Updated version of your code (based on answer by [itChi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48075782/3147123)) has another major error. You put spaces around the assignment operator when setting `TARGET_ENVIRONMENT = it`. This syntax is invalid and as a result `TARGET_ENVIRONMENT` is not assigned the specified value, thus the condition inside `evaluateEnvProp` function evaluates to false and `ENV_NODE` variable is not being set. Removing the spaces should solve the problem. You also did not call `evaluateEnvProp` as pointed out in update to @itChi's answer.

I'd highly recommend that you start using [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to verify correctness of your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, variables are global by default, so if you reference them in your `scpTAR` function, you will get a return value.

However, as a second method, should you wish, you can reference it like so:

```
scpTAR $ENV_NAME $ENV_NODE $ENV_WLS_DOMAIN $ENV_NODE_PATH
```

Then in your scpTAR function reference them as:

```
echo "$1 $2 $3 $4"
it xyx user1 path
```

Particularly useful should you wish to run code on another machine, run a remote script, or set your script up to pass variables as arguments from bash.

EDIT:

Sorry if I tread on someone's toes, but here is your answer without subshell:

```
evalEnvProp(){
 if [ ${TARGET_ENVIRONMENT} = "it" ]; then

 ENV_NAME=it
 ENV_NODE=xyx
 ENV_WLS_DOMAIN=user1
 ENV_NODE_PATH=path
 fi
 }  
scpTAR() {  
  echo $ENV_NODE_PATH
}

main(){  
  evalEnvProp   
  scpTAR   
}  
main
```

Update2:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
MASTER_HOSTNAME=`hostname | cut -d . -f1`
TARGET_ENVIRONMENT=it
evaluateEnvProp(){
if [ ${TARGET_ENVIRONMENT} = "it" ]; then
ENV_NAME=it && ENV_NODE=1cf62108e084
fi
}

scpTAR() {
echo ENV_NODE
echo ${ENV_NODE}
if [ ENV_NODE == ${MASTER_HOSTNAME} ] ; then
echo "scpTAR ENV_NODE = ${MASTER_HOSTNAME} " else
"echo 'scpTAR ssh other node than jenkins server >ENV_NODE=${MASTER_HOSTNAME}'"

fi

}
main(){
evaluateEnvProp
scpTAR
}
main
```

1. `MASTER_HOSTNAME` needs `` for the command. you are calling `hostname`. You can also accomplish this with `$()`
2. Spacing in the IF statement either side of the `=` sign. otherwise you are not evaluating, you are `setting` a variable.
3. In your edit you missed out a function call to `evaluateEnvProp` which failed because you didn't set the variable.

Comment: i have removed paranthesis.But still i couldnt able to fetch ENV_NODE value in second function scpTAR
set -x
MASTER_HOSTNAME=`hostname | cut -d . -f1`
TARGET_ENVIRONMENT=it

evaluateEnvProp(){
  if [ ${TARGET_ENVIRONMENT}=it ]; then
       ENV_NAME=it && ENV_NODE=1cf62108e084 
  fi
}

scpTAR() {
    echo ENV_NODE
  if [ ENV_NODE==${MASTER_HOSTNAME} ] ; then
      echo "scpTAR ENV_NODE = ${MASTER_HOSTNAME} "
   else 
       "echo 'scpTAR ssh other node than jenkins server ENV_NODE=${MASTER_HOSTNAME}'"
   
  fi
      
}
main(){
    scpTAR
    }
    main

Comment: @sudhir please format this properly so that we can help you.

Comment: This code is not very clear, for example you need spaces when using if [ ${TARGET_ENVIRONMENT}=it ] otherwise you are just setting TARGET_ENVIRONMENT Variable. Can you edit your post with your full code?